# Does enabling Hyper-V on Windows 8.1 slow down the system?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, hyper-v

From what I can tell when you enable HyperV in Windows 8.1, everything (including the host machine) becomes a virtual machine.  Sure, the host machine has more privileges but it's still just a virtual machine.

I want to know whether the host machine runs slower when HyperV is enabled (as a result of being a virtual machine)?

Comment: Hyper-V slows down GPU performance on the host

Comment: @Ramhound You are wrong.  See the winning answer [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/365798/why-does-the-task-manager-does-not-show-any-activity-from-hyper-v)